# Why selectExpr changes schema (to include id column)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### **UPDATE** (that makes the alarm false and void)

Rebuilt **2.2.0-SNAPSHOT** with the latest changes from the master and *without* my local changes to `def schema` in `Dataset`. IT WORKS. Sorry for the noise :(

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_121
Branch master
Compiled by user jacek on 2017-03-27T19:00:06Z
Revision 3fada2f502107bd5572fb895471943de7b2c38e4
Url https://github.com/apache/spark.git
Type --help for more information.

scala> spark.range(1).printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)


scala> spark.range(1).selectExpr("*").printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

---

While toying with `selectExpr` (in the **2.2.0-SNAPSHOT** from today's master) I noticed that the schema changes to include `id` column. I can't seem to explain it. Anyone?

I can reproduce it every time I start `spark-shell` by doing the following:

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT

scala> spark.range(1).printSchema
root
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)

scala> spark.range(1).explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint
Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Physical Plan ==
*Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

scala> spark.range(1).printSchema
root
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)

scala> spark.range(1).selectExpr("*").printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)

scala> val rangeDS = spark.range(1)
rangeDS: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [value: bigint]

scala> rangeDS.selectExpr("*").printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

p.s. Looks like I can't seem to reproduce it in **2.1.0**.

---

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_121
Branch master
Compiled by user jacek on 2017-03-27T03:43:09Z
Revision 3fbf0a5f9297f438bc92db11f106d4a0ae568613
Url https://github.com/apache/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

Comment: I don't think `selectExpr` is relevant here. I reckon it is because `id` [is the SQL field name](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e04c05cf41a125b0526f59f9b9e7fdf0b78b8b21/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L533).

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce the problem with clean build on [3fbf0a5f9297f438bc92db11f106d4a0ae56861](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/3fbf0a5f9297f438bc92db11f106d4a0ae568613).

Comment: Updated the question. Re your first comment about `id` being the SQL field name, is that against what you experience per your 2nd comment?

Comment: I actually get `id` all the way. No `value` at all :/ Only `(1 to 100).toDS` gives `value` in my case, but then `value` is preserved after `selectExpr("*")`. Hmmm.... It looks like we use the same commit.

Comment: One way or another the suspect is `output.head.name`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you compiled it yourself?

Comment: @asettouf Yes, and am rebuilding it with no local changes (as I'm more and more to think that they may've been the culprit).

Comment: That might explain the differences I see with the nightly build they provide, do you follow the documentation when buiding Spark? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#apache-maven

Comment: This is what I'm using for the build -- `./build/mvn -Phadoop-2.7,yarn,mesos,hive,hive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean install` I'll know more in a moment. Building now...

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer lies in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala), for every "expression" that you pass in `selectExpr`, the function creates a new column and then add the original columns:

```
def selectExpr(exprs: String*): DataFrame = {
    select(exprs.map { expr =>
      Column(sparkSession.sessionState.sqlParser.parseExpression(expr))
    }: _*)
}
```

And if you take a look just above at what select does:

```
def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame = select((col +: cols).map(Column(_)) : _*)
```

You see that it concatenates new columns taken from the SQL expression and creates a new dataframe containing them, plus the ones from the original dataframe

**Edit** I tried with the 2.2.0 and I obtain:

```
res7: String = 2.2.0
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Thanks. What I miss in this explanation is why does `value` get mapped to `id`? Where does this happen?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I tried with the 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT and obtain the same for both lines. Could you try to add `.explain()` instead of `printSchema` ?

Comment: Updated. I'm wondering if it's just me and local changes.